# Glassfish doesnot start from Eclipse Helios SR2

Tags: port, glassfish-3, conflict, eclipse-3.6

I am trying to run Glassfish V3 Opens source edition from eclipse using the glassfish adapter.It gives me port conflict error.I have checked both 8080 as well as 4848 and both are free and not used by any process.I have disabled my firewall(NOD 32).
No matter what i do the external server just wont start.I deleted everything under the OSGI folder under the domain,i tried different verison of driver,nuthing seems to work.

I even downloaded Indigo and tried using the same, but i get the same error.

Somebody please Help!!

Comment: Can you start the server using the `asadmin` command?

Comment: @hage i am an amateur at this,not sure how to run it using asaadmin,but i could bring up the server by double clicking the startserv.bat and could access the admin panel via browser.I hope that helps.

Comment: That's weird. Are you really really really sure, that there is no other instance running? Did you run `stopserv.bat`? Can you connect to the admin console before trying to start GF in Eclipse?

Comment: Yes i ran stopserv.bat ,i could open the admin page via browser. and i crosschecked using nestat for port availability.

Comment: Ok this problem got solved when i placed the glassfish directory right beside the eclipse folder.The server started immediately after i copied the glassfish right beside the eclipse folder.As a precaution i created the workspace also on the same drive.Not sure if this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this problem got solved when i placed the glassfish directory right beside the eclipse folder.The server started immediately after i copied the glassfish right beside the eclipse folder.As a precaution i created the workspace also on the same drive.Not sure if this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The best is always to check if you have the latest plugin from this download center:
http://download.java.net/glassfish/eclipse/helios

Relative path of a GlassFish server should not matter at all...